# React : Edit data and save on local storage

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I am using `React Bootstrap table`. When I add an item in the list, i use the `local storage` to save data like that :

```
componentDidUpdate() {       
        localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(this.state.items))                
}
```

Now, i want to edit data on cell of bootstrap table with cellEdit :

```
<BootstrapTable data={this.props.items} cellEdit={this.cellEdit}>
       <TableHeaderColumn isKey='true' dataField='id'>Id</TableHeaderColumn>
       <TableHeaderColumn  dataField='content' dataSort={true} >Titre</TableHeaderColumn>
       <TableHeaderColumn  dataField='reference'>Réference</TableHeaderColumn>     
       <TableHeaderColumn dataField='docLibelle' >Libellé du document </TableHeaderColumn>  
       <TableHeaderColumn dataField='filePath' dataFormat={this.linkFormatter} >Url du document </TableHeaderColumn>                         
 </BootstrapTable>   

 cellEdit = {
    mode: 'click', // click cell to edit
    afterSaveCell: this.afterSaveCell
};

afterSaveCell(row, cellName, cellValue, newText) { 
    localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(this.state.itemsUpdate));
}
```

So, first i have an error:

> this is undefined.

Then, i don't know if it's the solution beacause it doesn't work. 
Help me in this, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is, You forgot to `bind` the `cellEdit` event, use this:

```
cellEdit={this.cellEdit.bind(this)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer

I modify this :

```
cellEdit = {
    mode: 'click', // click cell to edit
    afterSaveCell: this.afterSaveCell.bind(this)
};
```

The concept works, when I edit a data, the local storage changes. However my state is empty , it's normal because :

```
public constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {           
        itemsUpdate: []           
    }
}
```

But , I don't know how to get the data edited.Do you have an idea ? 
Thank you